# Gaming development for portables and remotely processing graphics - how possible this is?

Tags: mobile, cloud, gpu, game-development

Is it possible to process graphics remotely and send it to another device (like an iPhone), so you could run a game with better graphics than the iPhone itself could handle ?

I googled a bit but found little on the subject, just some things about GPU Cloud services but not many information.

I've seen the [OnLive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnLive) thing, and I guess the main issue to develop this for a phone would be network connection. Would it be feasible ? Viable ? Does it look like the future of gaming for portables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, no. iPhones have impressive resolution (on par with OnLive) but a data connection that comes nowhere near what's required. Furthermore, using a radionetwork also is demanding on the battery. So from both a cost and a technical perspective, a local GPU (included in many modern ARM SOCs) is a better solution.